# Can I use a Tomcat Server and MQTT?

Tags: tomcat, mqtt, iot

A question on style of coding an IoT application.
I have an IoT app that uses a server side app (Tomcat based) for some validation of data collected.

The client reads some data from a sensor, and sends it to a Tomcat server to validate and get extra data, then publishes the result to an MQTT topic. The Tomcat server does not use MQTT.

I realise it is technically possible for the Tomcat server app to do the MQTT publishing itself, but is it good practice? What are the pitfalls (if any) of this approach?

Similarly, can the Tomcat Server App be a subscriber?

I have a bad gut feeling about doing it this way, but a colleague thinks it will be OK.

Comment: There isn't really enough clarity in what you are asking here. This is multiple questions, some of which will lead to opinion based answers (which are off topic for Stack Overflow). Please see if you can [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58799880/edit) the question to make it more focused and possibly ask separate questions. It might help to describe the flow you think having the Tomcat instance being a MQTT subscriber would solve.

Comment: You should also probably read the doc on what a good question should contain https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

**I realise it is technically possible for the Tomcat server app to do the MQTT publishing itself, but is it good practice? What are the pitfalls (if any) of this approach?**

Its a common practice among industries to integrate mqtt client libraries and code in their server app code to get data (using subscriptions) from sensors as well process the received data based on some logic and maybe send it somewhere else. I guess the pitfalls would be as good as you code is.

**Similarly, can the Tomcat Server App be a subscriber?**

Yes, it can. You can view your server app as an mqtt client that can publish and subscribe (be a subscriber) at the same time to an MQTT server (broker).

Comment: Tomcat really doesn't have anywhere it makes much sense to run a subscriber. What application component would you run it in? It doesn't make sense in a Servlet as they are transient for the life of a HTTP request. A full JEE engine at least has EJBs which can be triggered on messages...